# urllib error when using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Whenever I run the below code in Python 3 I get a syntax error `invalid syntax`. The reason for this I assume is because print in python 3 has different syntax.

```
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import Request
import json

request = Request(
    "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
    dataAsJSON,
    { "Authorization" : "key="+MY_API_KEY,
      "Content-type" : "application/json"
    }
)

print urlopen(request).read()
```

however, when I change my last line to

```
result = urlopen(request).read()
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file
>   object. It cannot be of type str.

Comment: Python 3 print is a function so use it as `print()`. Try converting your string into `bytearray` using `ba = urlopen(request).read().encode('latin1')`

Comment: @Vinny still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your data to byte string before creating `request` object.

```
dataAsJSON = dataAsJSON.encode()
```